# linked list add node changes all nodes values instead of just one

Tags: c, linked-list

Alright I've been working on this for hours now and can't figure out my issue. I have a double linked list and when I try and add a new node to it it will change all the values in the linked list.

right now this is what I have:

```
void createSub(sibs *root, char *name, int size) {
    if (root->subSibs == NULL) {
        root->subSibs = (sibs *)malloc(sizeof(sibs));
        root->subSibs->name = name;
        root->subSibs->time_stamp = createTimeStamp();
        root->subSibs->nextSib = NULL;
    }

    sibs *temp = root->subSibs;
    if (temp != NULL) {
        while(temp->nextSib != NULL)
            temp = temp->nextSib;
    }
    sibs *t = (sibs *)malloc(sizeof(sibs));

    t->name = name;
    t->time_stamp = createTimeStamp();
    t->nextSib = NULL;

    if(temp != NULL)
        temp->nextSib = t;

    printf("root->subSibs->name = %s\n", root->subSibs->name);
    (root->numSub)++;
}
```

this might not be perfect considering I've changed it a million times. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

`root` is the root node I'm working with and `subSibs` is pointer to the linked list. What I am doing is adding a name and timestamp to each node in that linked list pointed to by `root->subSibs`.

What I get out is:

```
createSub(root, name1, size);
```

prints:

```
root->subSibs1: name1;

createSub(root, name2, size);
```

prints:

```
root->subSibs1: name2;
root->subSibs2: name2;
```

etc...

It will probably be some really really stupid mistake but any help would be amazing. I've been trying for hours and just need someone to tell me why it will change the names.

Also if I do `strcpy(root->subSibsi->name, name); for i = 0-5; root->subSibs1->name` prints garbage and then `root->subSibs2->name` prints correct name and then `root->subSibs3->name` prints garbage (same as `subSibs1->name`) and so on...

Comment: is there a else block missed after the initial if ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> t->name = name;
> ```

You are copying pointers. Instead you likely want to duplicate the memory:

```
t->name = strdup(name);
```

Or:

```
t->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
strcpy(t->name, name);
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was going to be some stupid mistake like this. Hours and hours it took me I completely forgot about strdup and (obviously) wasn't mallocing t->name; I appreciate the quick response!

Comment: @eric Use **one** of those solutions. `strdup` itself calls `malloc`. And remember to `free`.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information (like how you call the function) I guess that you have a single buffer (probably a char array) and that you pass the address to that same buffer for each call to `createSubs`. This will make every node you create to point to the same buffer, which will always contain the last string entered.

Answer (score 1):

In your node, **name is char ***. In other words it can point to some arbitrary memory location. To begin with it has some garbage value, so it points to nothing from programmers point of view and cannot to be used to store value - which is what you did.

Now if we allocate a portion of memory, big enough to store string pointed by argument **char *name** , we can make your node's name to point to it. Once you do that you can copy argument **name *** to node **name ***